# Global inbox misses messages generated during a day in the penalty box

Tags: bug, status-norepro, global-inbox, account-suspension

I recently did a bad thing at stackoverflow.com and got suspended for a day. I have not received any messages from that day in my global inbox. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked over comments and answers in reply to you during the suspension period, and they are all accounted for in your global inbox.

Is there a comment or post you can point to as "should be in the inbox, but isn't"?

Comment: How about comments for the answer for my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782714/gcc-vs-ms-c-compiler-for-maintaining-api-backwards-binary-compatibility/4833439#4833439 Should I receive them to my Inbox? If not then this bug should be probably converted to a feature request.

Comment: @developer - only comments directly in reply to you should go into your inbox.  That is, comments on **your** questions or answers, or comments `@developer` in comment threads you have participated in.  This is [status-bydesign].